# Submitting HTML form with javascript Onclick

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick

I am trying to submit my HTML form with javascript rather than using an `submit` input type.

However I am presented with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function
```

Below is the structure of my code:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="popup_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="popup_raffle_entry">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1"><div class="popup_wrapper"><h1 class="container_title" style="-webkit-border-radius:0px;border-radius:0px;margin-bottom:5px;">
           Raffle Entry - Galil (Factory New) | </h1><p>The price for one ticket in this raffle is <span style="color:#4E17A7;">1000 Flip Coins</span>.</p><p><span style="color:#4E17A7;">1000 Flip Coins</span> is currently equivalent to
           <span style="color:#4E17A7;">$10</span></p><br><p style="position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;font-weight:bold;">Your current Flip Coin Balance is:
    <span class="profile_category_r"><img src="images/flipcoin.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:290px;top:2px;">
           <span style="margin-left:35px;color:#4E17A7;">1000</span></span></p><p style="margin-top:10px;">Please choose the number of tickets to buy:</p><input type="text" name="number_of_tickets" id="number_of_tickets" placeholder="Between 1 and 10"></form><br clear="all"><p class="buy_tickets_button" onclick="document.getElementById('popup_form').submit();">Buy Tickets Now</p><a class="buy_flipcoins_button" href="index.php?page=purchase">Purchase Flip Coins</a><p class="close_popup_button">Close Popup</p><br clear="all"><br clear="all"></div>
```

I have tried moving the java script function both inline and in a scripts.js page but it doesnt make a difference.

Comment: it would be easier to help if you posted the actual html that your browser is interpreting and not the php. Generally though you would want to check that a. the element that you are targeting exists by using a `console.log("element", document.getElementById(...))` and b. that you don't have a button type submit in the form.

Comment: May I ask why your title and tags say JS when your question only contains PHP? At least include the JavaScript function where you are trying to accomplish this.

Comment: @SteynvanEsveld Is so you are saying the last line of the code does not contain Javascript? Forgive me, didnt know document.getElementByID was php.....

Comment: this question should be rewritten in html/js syntax. the php makes the code much harder to read and distracts the reader from whatever JS issue is being asked about

Comment: I missed that particular line, because of the highlighting, my apologies. Does your HTML form contain the name 'submit' somewhere? Like "<button name="submit">" Because this is known for giving problems. If not, we would need to see the HTML.

Comment: Okay i will update with pure html. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a input name="submit", this is causing the problem.

Also, there is no button in your html.

Comment: I thought the whole point of submitting via JS is so we dont need the submit button???? I have seen it been done elsewhere

Comment: The actual problem is the input name submit. As this is overwriting the original submit function. It can be done without a button, but why would you over complicate things? Use a button with type submit and put a preventDefault on the click with JS.

Comment: err i dont have an input name = "submit"

Comment: " <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1">" no?

Comment: Awesome! Could you accept the answer so more people can find it? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use a tool like Firebug that will trace Javascript code and especially in your case, said if submit is called and which return it got.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer though.